Simple HTML z-index context issue when dragging a div with javascript
I am trying to create a "viewport" effect where I can drag a div around the screen. I want to have controls at the top but I am having issues with the dragged content moving over the controls div.
Update: When i added "position: relative" to the div with z-index: 4 the text appears above the green box but I want the green box to disappear.
Update 2: also add overflow: hidden on your parent div.
I looked around and found the following articles which explained a lot but i'm dumb.
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html
https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/
I have some code from the net that demonstrates the issue. I want the green rectangle to "move under" the other content div (with id "message").


const content = document.getElementById('content');
const message = document.getElementById('message');
let isDragging = false;
let startX, startY, initialX, initialY;

content.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDragging = true;
  startX = e.clientX;
  startY = e.clientY;
  initialX = content.offsetLeft;
  initialY = content.offsetTop;
  content.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
  message.innerHTML = "Mousedown, initial X: " + initialX + ",  initialY: " + initialX;
});
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (isDragging) {
    const currentX = e.clientX;
    const currentY = e.clientY;
    const dx = currentX - startX;
    const dy = currentY - startY;
    content.style.left = `${initialX + dx}px`;
    content.style.top = `${initialY + dy}px`;
  }
});
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDragging = false;
  content.style.cursor = 'grab';
});
// Prevent text selection while dragging
content.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
});
#draggable {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 76vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px inset;
}

#viewport {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: grab;
  user-select: none;
  /* Prevent text selection */
  background-color: green;
  opacity: .99;
}
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 4">
  <div>
    <span id="message">Other content</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="draggable" style="z-index: 3">
  <div id="viewport" style="z-index: 2">
    <div id="content" style="z-index: 1">
      DRAG ME
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Is this a simple fix that I just can't see?
Thanks in advance.

Ok. It was position: relative and then overflow: hidden
I can see it going underneath now.


        const content = document.getElementById('content');
        const message = document.getElementById('message');
        let isDragging = false;
        let startX, startY, initialX, initialY;

        content.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
            isDragging = true;
            startX = e.clientX;
            startY = e.clientY;
            initialX = content.offsetLeft;
            initialY = content.offsetTop;
            content.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
            message.innerHTML = "Mousedown, initial X: "+initialX+",  initialY: "+initialX;
        });
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            if (isDragging)
            {
                const currentX = e.clientX;
                const currentY = e.clientY;
                const dx = currentX - startX;
                const dy = currentY - startY;
                content.style.left = `${initialX + dx}px`;
                content.style.top = `${initialY + dy}px`;
            }
        });
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
            isDragging = false;
            content.style.cursor = 'grab';
        });
        // Prevent text selection while dragging
        content.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
  
            #draggable {
                position: relative;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 76vh;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                border: 1px inset;
            }
            #viewport {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }
            #content {
                position: absolute;
                width: 200px;
                height: 150px;
                color: white;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                cursor: grab;
                user-select: none; /* Prevent text selection */
                background-color: green;
                opacity: .99;
            }
    <div style="position: relative; z-index: 4;">
        <span id="message">Other content</span>
    </div>
    <div id="draggable" style="z-index: 3; overflow: hidden">
        <div id="viewport" style="z-index: 2">
            <div id="content" style="z-index: 1">
                DRAG ME
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



I can just constrain it via javascript now.

Thanks for sharing your answer, glad you figured it out
